# How should I serialize a trie containing a queue of strings in each node

Tags: c++, serialization, memory-management, deserialization, trie

I have built a t9 keyboard in c++ using a 8 way trie, where each node looks like :-

```
const int R=8;
    
class node
    {
        queue<string> words;
        node* keys[R];
        public:
        node()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<R;keys[i++]=NULL);
        }
        queue<string> getWords() { return words; }
        void addWord(string w) { words.push(w); }
        void addKeys(node* k,int p) { keys[p]=k; }
        node* getKey(int p) { return keys[p]; }
    }*root=NULL;
```

The queue is used to store words like "fog" and "dog" because both of them have the same keypad input "1-4-2".

Right now I am using a dictionary of only around 60,000 words, so I am getting away with initializing the trie every time the program starts. But, loading time and memory usage will massively increase if there are more words. So, I came across Serialization and De-Serialization methods.
But I have no idea how would I do that with a queue of strings present in each node.

Any other suggestions of changing the data-structure a bit are also welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: *But, loading time and memory usage will massively increase if there are more words.* -- In this day and age of computers, processors, memory, and speed, 60,000 words is a hiccup.  So how many words are you expecting?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Around a million.

Comment: Have you actually measured reading a million words, or just assuming it will be slow?  When you say "massively increase", what specific timing tests have you done to see if the increase is massive?  Also, a million words, given today's computers is far more manageable in terms of memory than 20 or 30 years ago.  We are not back in the MSDOS days.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have not measured reading a million words but I am certain it would take around 4 seconds to create the trie on my machine as it takes 0.22s to insert 60,000 ( O(m*n) ) time complexity to insert in a trie. This is not a huge project of mine so I don't even know if 4s are fine or not, and I want to implement serialization in a practical way.

Comment: 4 seconds sounds very reasonable to me for a million words.  Maybe just put up a "Loading Data..." splash screen if you want some sort of visual prompt to the user as to what is happening.

Comment: Oh! Ok after seeing quicksort and mergesort like algorithms perform operations within seconds on million entries, I guess my standards for performance of algorithm rose!!

Comment: I'm not saying there couldn't be an improvement over the 4 seconds, but given a million words, 4 seconds is a very good starting point.